# В каких случаях используется try/finally без except

Tags: python

Можете написать практические примеры, в которых реально используется только try/finally без except

Comment: Посмотрите про контекстные менеджеры.

Answer (score 2):

В тех случаях, когда какое-то действие должно быть выполнено вне зависимости от того, случились какие-то ошибки или нет. Например, вы в начале работы создаёте временный файл, а в конце хотите его удалить. Вы выделяете/открываете какой-то ресурс, а потом вам обязательно нужно его утилизировать/закрыть.

```
create_some_resource()
try:
    ...
finally:
    delete_some_resource()
```

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но если будет try/except/finally. Finally все равно же выполнится. Мне интересно есть ли какой то профит без использования except.

Comment: Так у меня и нет тут `except` и он не нужен в общем случае. Может там в теле вызываются какие-то функции, которые не бросают наружу исключения. Эта конструкция чисто вот чтобы не забыть утилизировать открытый ранее ресурс

Comment: Т.е правильно понимаю, что без  `except`  в основном используют, когда уверены что в теле у тебя нет ошибок, которые бросают наружу исключения?

Comment: @telate22 Даже если и не уверены. Пусть ошибки и будут выброшены наружу, может задумка такая. Но `finally` при этом всё-равно отработает.